# Can I use weight paint in the middle of a face?

Tags: vertices, faces, weight-painting

I've been following along with [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25N775uHb_4&t=1883s) (you don't need to watch it). I made a plate mesh, and it's quite low-poly. The top of it is only one (1) n-gon. I was hoping to use weight paint in the middle of that n-gon, but it seems I'm only allowed to weight paint around its vertices. As the title asks, is there a way to weight paint in the middle of that face, or do I have to use triangulate or some other modifier to add vertices?

Thank you!

EDIT: Thanks, those were exactly the kind of answers I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! Weight painting specifically weights vertices, so no, there is no way to weight the middle of a face. A vertex is the most basic piece of a mesh, so in order to define how a mesh should look or behave, it needs to have vertices wherever you want there to be detail/information.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on previous answers, the "weigh paint" on a face is simply a [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) ("lerp") of the values at constituent vertices. This means that it has no value independent of that, however, you can create one with CTRL+R (loop cut) or a simple committed subdivision (usually with W).

That said, excessive vertices on weight paint mode can severely tax your machine; it is not as cheap an operation as rendering. So, it's usually best to either find a way to work with the original vertices, or add no more additional vertices than you need to.